# How to find the speed of a car ascending on an incline when the mass is a time function?

Tags: calculus, physics, classical-mechanics

The problem is as follows:

> A VW bus is ascending over a ramp as indicated in the figure from
> below. The bus has a power of $120\,kW$ to ascend over the incline. If
> the friction with the road and air is $\frac{3}{25}$ of its weight.
> Find the speed which the bus is ascending in kilometers per hour.
> Assume that the mass of the bus is $2t$.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&108\,\frac{km}{h}\\
2.&90\,\frac{km}{h}\\
3.&72\,\frac{km}{h}\\
4.&36\,\frac{km}{h}\\
5.&54\,\frac{km}{h}\\
\end{array}$

I'm totally lost in this question because of the fact that the mass seems to be changing with time as it is given $2t$

In the case to find the speed the only formula which comes to my mind is:

$P=F\cdot v$

But what force should it be assumed here?. Can someone help me?.

If the speed is held constant then this means that the force is:

$F= f_{frictional}$

$F=\frac{3}{25}mg$

But I dont' know what else can be used as I think there will be an integration. Can someone give me some help with this?.

Comment: $p=mv \implies \frac{dp}{dt}=F=m\frac{dv}{dt}+v\frac{dm}{dt}$. When $v$ is constant, $\frac{dv}{dt}=0$

Comment: The fact that the force will keep increasing intuitively suggests that the velocity should reduce with time since the engine is delivering a constant power

Comment: +1 for what @DhanviSreenivasan said. Are you sure that the mass is $2t$ and not $20$ or some other fixed value?

Answer (score 1):

The mass of the bus is 2 metric tonnes = 2000 kg. It is constant.

The engine is supplying power to move the bus up the incline against friction :
$$P_1=\frac{3}{25}mgv$$
It is also supplying power to raise the bus vertically against gravity :
$$P_2=mgv\sin\theta$$
The total power supplied by the engine is $P_1+P_2$. No integration required. Probably more suitable for Physics SE.